# Boolean formulas over omega automata

Tags: logic, automata, first-order-logic

I've been reading on omega automata(automata on infinite words) and stumbled upon a definition involving logic which caught me off guard.

For example, on Buchi automata the definition I originally saw was :

An omega automaton $M = (Q,\Sigma,\delta,I,F)$ is called a Buchi automaton if for every $w : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \Sigma$ there exists a run $r$ so that $inf(r) \cap F \neq \emptyset$ where $inf$ is a function

$$inf(\sigma) = \left\{ w \in \Sigma ~: \exists^{\infty} n \in \mathbb{N} : \sigma(w) = s \right\}$$ 
where $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \Sigma$ is the function describing each letter of a word.
These definitions are seen at [1](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/papers/pdf/tcs-96-2.pdf) and [2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~eid1/ba.pdf).

However what I found [here](http://www.automata.rwth-aachen.de/~loeding/diploma_loeding.pdf) and [here](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAAahUKEwij0a-OiqbHAhVH3SwKHYN7BXo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.rice.edu%2F~vardi%2Fpapers%2Fcharme031.ps.gz&ei=GZDMVePgKce6swGD95XQBw&usg=AFQjCNHT1lQQdB1_1bOQC1XsCrsrMmoc5g&bvm=bv.99804247,d.bGg) involve a new definition where the transition function is defined as $\delta : Q \times \Sigma \rightarrow B^{+}(Q)$ instead of $Q \times\Sigma \rightarrow P(Q)$.

$B^{+}(Q)$ is said to be a positive boolean formula. This [thesis](http://www.automata.rwth-aachen.de/~loeding/diploma_loeding.pdf) pretty much explains everything but I have not taken a course in Math Logic and can't understand why he involves formulas in the definitions. He also then defines the behaviour of the automatons using quantifiers, eg.

---

[image]

Comment: What is precisely your question? What do you not understand in these definitions?

Comment: I don't understand how formulas are involved in the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Muller automata**. A path $\pi$ is accepting if $Inf(\pi) \in \mathcal{F}$. This is equivalent to saying that there exists $F \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $Inf(\pi) = F$. In the logical setting, this condition should be written as

> $Inf(\pi)$ exactly satisfies $Acc$,

where $Acc$ is an appropriate formula. 
Thus $Acc$ can be written as $\bigvee_{F \in \mathcal{F}} \varphi_F$, where $F$ exactly satisfies an appropriate formula $\varphi_F$. For this, it suffices to take
$$
  \varphi_F = \bigwedge_{q \in F}q \wedge \bigwedge_{q \in Q-F} \neg q
$$
a formula which exactly defines $F$ (see Definition 1.1 of the thesis for a formal definition). Indeed, the unique truth assignment $v:Q \to \{True, False\}$ that makes $\varphi_F$ true is given by
$$
v(q) = \begin{cases}
True &\text{if }q \in F \\
False &\text{if }q \notin F 
\end{cases}
$$
Altogether, you get the acceptance condition
$$
  Acc = \bigvee_{F \in \mathcal{F}} \bigl(\bigwedge_{q \in F}q \wedge \bigwedge_{q \in Q-F} \neg q \bigr)
$$
For instance, if you take $Q = \{q_1, q_2, q_3\}$, $\mathcal{F} = \{F_1, F_2\}$, where $F_1 = \{q_1, q_2\}$ and $F_2= \{q_1, q_3\}$, the formula will be
$(q_1 \wedge q_2 \wedge \neg q_3) \vee (q_1 \wedge q_3 \wedge \neg q_2)$.

**Rabin's conditions** can be represented by a logical formula in a similar way.

Comment: What are the formulas used?? I have not taken a course in Logic yet. My question is how are the formulas and boolean logics involved in the definition.

Comment: I am sorry, but you should read carefully Definition 1.1 of the thesis and understand it, possibly by reading a basic introduction to logic. If you do not understand the very first definition of the thesis, you might be in serious trouble to understand the rest.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that I need to get familiar with logic to understand, thought I could catch the point without but guess that won't happen. At the muller acceptance condition, are these the bounded existential and bounded universal quantifiers (read as "there exists an $F$ in $\mathcal{F}$" and "for $q$ in $\mathcal{F}$" respectively) ??

Comment: Suppose that $\mathcal{F} = \{F_1, \dots, F_n\}$. Then $F \in \mathcal{F}$ just means $F= F_1$ or $F= F_2$ or ... or $F = F_n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I understand definition 1.1 but can't understand how these formulas describe the acceptance conditions of each automaton. I'm trying for so long to understand but can't. How did you get to these formulas??

Comment: I added a few lines. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere. Could you post the acceptance formula of a Muller automaton with $Q = \left\{q_1,q_2,q_3 \right\}$ and $F=\left\{q_1,g_2 \right\}$ ? Just to know I got it right and evaluates to true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26983/discussion-between-j-e-pin-and-nickolas).